# Xcode Unit Tests Crash, could not load inserted library IDEBundleInjection

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode8, dyld

I've got an annoying issue with UnitTests in Xcode 8.1.
Trying to run a basic test on my iPad iOS 10.1.1 causes a crash due to the following error:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '__PLATFORMS__/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection' because image not found
```

I have yet to find a solution anywhere though some posts have suggested it could be related to the Code Signing for the unit test target. The code signing looks correct, the tests clean build, I deleted derived data, still seeing this error.

Comment: I have also been running in to this issue. I have to restart the phone in order to fix it. Changing signing to manual, like some people suggest, did not work for me. Are you using waitForExpectations in your tests? I get the error when I keep timing out and failing XCTFail. It doesn't appear to happen anytime after I succeed my tests.

Answer (score 1):

No amount of restarting or signing fixed this for me.  Only thing that works seems to be turning off debugging.

[image: Screenshot of disabling debugging for iOS tests schemes]

Do this for each scheme on iOS targets.  The implication is that you won't be able to step into your unit tests on devices with the debugger.

Hence, this is really a work-around, not a solution, but I'm posting it anyway as the checkbox is sufficiently obscure that it took me a while to try this and find my test would now run on the device.

I have Xcode bots running for continuous integration, and a real device plugged into my CI machine, so I need this to work.

I'm not sure if its an Xcode bug: if folks think it is then I'll make a report.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I filed a report and didn't get any solution back other then telling me to wait for the next update of XCode. You should file a report as well so it becomes a higher priority issue for them.

Comment: OK, I've logged a bug as well.  I did a minimal proof and determined that the issue manifests with an out-of-the-box new project, so its definitely a bug.  Just doing File > New Project - Unit tests: Yes - and trying to run those on a device causes the crash.

Comment: This is still a problem in Xcode 11, but not when testing on an iOS 13 device. Testing on an iOS 11 device requires debugging executable to be turned off.